# Getting errors while updating Kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

I am getting errors while updating and upgrading kali linux

```
apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

error>

```
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali sana InRelease                                 
Ign:2 http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates InRelease
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali sana Release  
  404  Not Found
Err:4 http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali sana Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

But doing just update doesnt give any errors  but upgrade does and due to this i am not able to install new applications
what should i do?

I have changed repository address to

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

and

```
deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
```

this
from the official kali site

```
[kali][1]
```

and now getting the error >

```
    Get:2 http://old.kali.org/kali sana InRelease [20.3 kB]                        
Err:2 http://old.kali.org/kali sana InRelease                      
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
Get:1 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Err:1 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://old.kali.org/kali sana InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
E: The repository 'http://old.kali.org/kali sana InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

got this error.

Comment: If you wonder why you are getting downvotes, Kali is a Linux distribution intended for seasoned Linux Administrators who are also seasoned security researchers and who already know how to overcome simple issues like the one you have here. It is NOT made for the faint of heart, if you do not have Linux qualifications you are better served by Debian, CoreOS, Mint, or Ubuntu, really, Kali will drive you crazy and we want you to enjoy Linux!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Kali Linux documentation](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories):

> The single most common causes of a broken Kali Linux installation are following unofficial advice, and particularly arbitrarily populating the system’s `sources.list` file with unofficial repositories. The following post aims to clarify what repositories should exist in `sources.list`, and when they should be used.
>
> Any additional repositories added to the Kali `sources.list` file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL.
>
> [...]
>
> Retired Kali sana (2.0) Repositories
>
> For access to the retired sana repositories, have the following entries in your sources.list:
>
> ```
> deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
> # For source package access, uncomment the following line
> # deb-src http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
> ```

Comment: its not working

Comment: @user8465966 Please update the question with what's happening when you are following the official documentation regarding the retired Sana repositories. I'm not personally using Kali (or Linux at all) and it's hard for me to know what "not working" actually means (what you did and what happened). This info should go into the question.

Comment: That particular page does not exist

Comment: @user8465966 If the repository mentioned in the official documentation is not accessible, I suggest that you use one of the the Kali Linux Community Support alternatives listed in the documentation here to ask about it: https://docs.kali.org/category/community

Comment: still getting the same error