# Can't install anything with apt-get on Kali

Tags: linux, apt, sudo, kali-linux, virtual-machine

I tried running `sudo apt-get install apktool` and got:

```
Reading package list... Done
Reading dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apktool
```

I ran `sudo apt-get update` and got:

```
Ign:1 http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://http.kali.org/kali sana InRelease   
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali sana Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Ign:1 http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates InRelease
Ign:1 http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates InRelease
Err:1 http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'security.kali.org'
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali sana Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I make `apt-get` work so I can install stuff?

Also: I am running kali as a vm in VMware... It is connected to the internet, but not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/5361#5361

Comment: @RomeoNinov Humor me?

Comment: No, read the Q/A. And if you ask this question, Kali is not for you.

Comment: @RomeoNinov well thanks for the tip. The thing is, I only want kali for the specific tools kali has, and because every tutorial I watch uses kali. I guess I'll have to figure it out the hard way...

Comment: As it is mentioned in the Q/A reinstall from fresh copy and then continue. And if you want to use `apktool` follow installation guide: https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/ As this tool need only `java` you can install it on virtually ANY Linux distribution

Comment: @RomeoNinov Okay, thanks so much. And sorry if I'm an annoying newbie...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get updates to Kali with updated source.list: "does not have a Release file"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608004/cant-get-updates-to-kali-with-updated-source-list-does-not-have-a-release-fil)

Comment: @Stewart when I run apt-get clean && apt-get purge && apt autoremove  (like in the question) I get  E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied) E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Comment: Run the commands as `root`: `sudo apt-get .....`

Comment: @RomeoNinov I am...

Comment: If you can't aquire the `dpkg` frontend, then that means you are either not root, or another process is already using it.  At this point you should really read this: 
https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/272848

Comment: @Stewart You're the 2nd person to send me that! Is this question famous?

Comment: @KovyJacob  It saves a lot of repetition. Usually, anyway.

Comment: @Paul_pedant what does?

Comment: We see hundreds of kali install questions like this.  Most people don't have the energy to answer them anymore.  Most of those questions aren't answered anymore.  It's a phenomenon unique to Kali. Ubuntu/Debian/Fedora/Redhat/Arch/Mint/ElementaryOS users don't have these types of problems.

Comment: @Stewart The phenomena is the amount of questions or the unwillingness to answer ;-)

Comment: @stewart Joking

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting errors while updating Kali linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423173/getting-errors-while-updating-kali-linux)

Comment: The phenomenon is "people who have no unix/linux experience ignoring the big fat warnings on Kali's own homepage about how it isn't meant for and shouldn't be used by beginners or as a desktop system, resulting in a flood of questions that are all best answered by 'For the love of gods or demons, *please* install something other than Kali if you're serious about learning linux"' "

Comment: @shadur I'm not going to pretend to be a linux purist looking to learn linux, I merely want Kaliu for all the preinstalled tools.

Comment: Purism has nothing to do with it. The fact that *Kali linux is not designed to be used by people who don't know linux* is.

Comment: @shadur I guess I'll have to suffer through...

Answer (score 1):

The generic recommendation is to install fresh copy of Kali Linux. This and few other things are explained in this [meta Q/A](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/101265).

You do not need Kali to run `apktool`. Just follow the [installation guide](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/) and you will be able to install it on virtually any Linux distribution (where you can install `java`).

Answer (score -1):

Kali Sana is an EOL release, it is no longer maintained. You need to migrate from Kali Sana to Kali rolling. Upgrading the installed system is not guaranteed, a fresh installation is more suitable, as said @Romeo Ninov.

Next step; The `apktool` is available in Kali repositories:

```
sudo apt install apktool
```

The VMware image can be downloaded from [here](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines). (Don't make chage the `sources.list`)

Comment: I downloaded the vmware file from kali.org 4 days ago and didn't change anything... How would a fresh installation help?

Comment: @KovyJacob you should download the vmare image from here https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines